# Enable :active state in IE7 with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7

I've searched for a simple jQuery plugin to enable the active state in IE7, but I've only been able to find IE7-js, which doesn't play well with my current javascript.

I think I could build this myself, but I figure someone else has already done a better job of it than I would. Is there a solid jQuery plugin that does this already?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by "enable?" Do you mean "add support for the CSS pseudo-class `:active`"?

Comment: That's what I meant @MattBall

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE7 should work just fine with `:active` on anchors (`<a>`), as long as the anchor has the `href` attribute ([source](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-active)).

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Unfortunately, since the site I'm working on is very Ajax-ified, plenty of anchors don't have hrefs, so this won't fly :(. I would use href="#", but I need to prevent the page from jumping around.

Comment: use #nogo it will not jump or use event.preventDefault()

Comment: @Dan - Could you use `href="#"` plus a little JS?  Something like `$('a[href="#"]').click(function() {return false;});` might let Matt's answer work for you.

Comment: Yasir's suggestion is pretty good, if you use `href="#some_nonexistent_element_id"` that should not cause any jumping.

Comment: Thanks @Xavier. I tried a quick implementations of what you recommended, and that didn't work for me.

Comment: @Yasir I think that will work for me. I was hoping for a js solution, that way I wouldn't have to add extra markup to all of the links I've created so far, but it seems like I might have to do that.